# Copy from the last row of a column until the end of spreadsheet (variable number every time)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, string-length

using a google apps script I need to copy data from spreadsheet #1, take it to the last row of spreadsheet #2 and later, copy the formula in last row-1 (number of row before the data is pasted) from spreadsheet #2 the length of the data that I've just copied

I've tried several ways but none works fine.
For the one below I tried inserting a formula in cell N1 of the spreadsheet #2 so that it shows the diference in the number of rows with data into two different columns. Then I tell the script to set the formula from lastrow to lastrow + that value.

When I run the script it copies the formula 19 times but N1 was 4 times. Then I tried to correct it and say: lastrow + the value of N1-15 and worked fine. 
However the next time I tried I inserted 8 values instead of 4, and it copied the formula 12 times.

```
function OrdenarRango() {

//  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PEDIDOS SIN ORDENAR").sort(5)

  //Ordena los datos del rango según la columna E en orden descendente
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("PEDIDOS SIN ORDENAR");
var range = sheet1.getRange("A2:F");
range.sort({column: 5, ascending: false})

//Borra los valores del rango A2:D
var A = sheet1.getRange("A2:F").getValues();
var borrar = sheet1.getRange("A2:D").clearContent();

//Pega los valores en la última fila de PEDIDOS 2020
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zF84h_gR0zHPqwobYyuOQlo50L2ktpZr2e4orMNtqE8/edit#gid=382646794'); 
var sheet2 = ss1.getSheetByName("PEDIDOS 2020"); 
var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow() + 1; 

var destRange = sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 1, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);

//Copia las fórmulas del rango

var rango = sheet2.getRange("N1").getValue()
var formulas = sheet2.getRange(lastRow-1, 10, 1, 1).getFormulasR1C1();
var destino = sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 10, lastRow+rango, 1);
destino.setFormulaR1C1(formulas)
}
```

I have also tried this, which only copies the formula once:

```
var rango = sheet2.getRange("N1").getValue()
var formulas = sheet2.getRange(lastRow-1, 10, 1, 1).getFormulasR1C1();
for (i= 0; i<=rango; i++) {
var destino = sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 10, 1, 1);
destino.setFormulaR1C1(formulas)}
```

And this one, which creates an infinite loop:

```
var rango = sheet2.getRange("N1").getValue()

while (rango > 0) {
var formulas = sheet2.getRange(lastRow-1, 10, 1, 1).getFormulasR1C1();
var destino = sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 10, 1, 1);
destino.setFormulaR1C1(formulas)}
```

At the begining I tried inserting something similar to A.length though I don't remember exactly the code. Anyway it didn't work either.

What's wrong about the code. How could it be fixed?

[Data before running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2E0G.png)

[image]

[Data after running the script. I need to know the code for each product and the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHmYb.png)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some images to give us an example of what you are trying to do.  I'd be glad to help, but I just don't understand what you're asking. And your code doesn't make much sense to me and of course your comments are in Spanish that's not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function OrdenarRango() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("sh1");
  var range=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,6);
  range.sort({column: 5, ascending: false})
  var A=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
  var borrar=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,4).clearContent();
  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(''); 
  var sh2=ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  var lastRow=sh2.getLastRow() + 1; 
  var destRange=sh2.getRange(lastRow,1,A.length,A[0].length).setValues(A);
  var formulas=sh2.getRange(lastRow-1, 10, 1, 1).getFormulasR1C1();
  var destino=sh2.getRange(lastRow,10,sh2.getLastRow()-lastRow+1,1);
  destino.setFormulaR1C1(formulas)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper, it copies the formula perfectly now. However there's a new problem that I don't understand: when it sorts the data, it doesn't respect the relation to the data that is contained in the other columns. For example if in row 2 there is (imagine one word per column): red dog, bike, computer. In row 3: green cat boat table. In row 4 appears orange, bird, car, computer again. Then the script sorts everything that contains computer and in row 3, you can find green, cat, boat, computer. It's weird because the sorting worked fine before

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You speak of the first 4 columns and  you are sorting on column5 descending.  Perhaps you can make it more clear about what you describing.  Try some images that explain it without words.

Comment: I edited the question and it has 2 images now. The content of each row should stay in the same row after sorting by column 5 because in that column there's the name of a supplier and it has to go with the product, number of items...